# Are there alternatives to using a MySQL database for simple tasks like this?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I want a webpage containing only a tick box. I wanted it to be possible for anyone to change the value of the tick box, and then the value to update for anyone checking the page, would I have to use a MySQL database? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You need to persist the state of that checkbox somewhere... whether that's a database or a file or a data caching system like redis

Comment: No, you would not necessarily need to use a database ( of whatever flavour ) - you could have an xml, json, txt file etc but a db takes aways a lot of the pain associated with writeable files and editing the contents of said files

Comment: Do you need the state to be updated on a page even if it's already loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a really simple thing. Of course you can use a database like MySQL for it, but it is seriously not needed in any way. You just have one value, so you could have a text file with that value and it would work too. It depends on what data you want to store.

A database is good because it offers you for example things like the **query**.